# ERRO ao selecionar um simulado

Tags: java, sql, jsf, xhtml, controller

Estou com um problema de subscrição.

Eu tenho uma tela que recupera ciclos que estão em abertos de acordo com o curso do usuário e para cada ciclo desse já tem um simulado salvo, ou seja, um relacionamento.

BEAN:

@PostConstruct

```
private void init(){
    this.ciclosCurso = CicloDAO.buscaCicloPorCursoDoUsuario(
                codigoCursoUsuario, dataMaxima);
}
```

O problema que estou enfretando é o seguinte:

Na hora de responder um ciclo, se tem 2 ciclos ele pega apenas o ultimo: Eu sei aonde tá o problema só não sei como resolver.

Vejam bem:

```
No meu dataTable eu tenho: 

                    <p:column headerText="Responder Simulado" style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                        <p:commandButton id="responderSimulado" icon="ui-icon-check" title="Responder Simulado" update="@this :frmCadastroSimulado:exibePerguntas"
                            actionListener="#{responderSimuladoBean.recuperaSimuladoDeAcordoComCicloSelecionado}">
                            <f:param name="ciclo" value="#{ciclo.codigo}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
```

No método recuperaSimuladoDeAcordoComCicloSelecionado() na minha bean tá assim:

```
public void recuperaSimuladoDeAcordoComCicloSelecionado() {
        for (Ciclo ciclo : ciclosCurso) {
            this.simulado = this.simuladoDAO.buscaSimuladoPorCiclo(ciclo
                    .getCodigo());
        }
```

Só para complementar:

```
select s from Simulado s where s.ciclo.codigo = :idCiclo
```

Resumindo, eu recupero um simulado pelo código do ciclo. O problema é que no trecho de código acima ele recupera o simulado que eu quero e depois recupera o outro simulado que foi achado no PostConstruct, entretanto eu não pedi pra responder ele, ou seja, ele acha o simulado com o código que eu quero e depois sobrescreve.

Como resolvo?

Comment: Qual o escopo do seu bean?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares é ViewScoped.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um `SessionScoped`? No caso, só pra nível de teste mesmo.